# SQL - creating a list of custom dates between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble compiling a query than can do the following:

1. I have a table which has a **startDate** and **endDate** [tblPayments]
2. I have a column which stores a specific **paymentDay** [tblPayments]

**Data**

```
paymentID        startDate           endDate          paymentDay
    1            2016-01-01         2016-12-31            25
    2            2015-06-01         2016-06-30            16
```

I am trying to generate a `SELECT` query which will split this specific table into separate lines based on the amount of months between these two dates, and set the **paymentDay** as the day for these queries

**Example Output**

```
paymentID       expectedDate
    1            2016-01-25   
    1            2016-02-25   
    1            2016-03-25   
    1            2016-04-25   
    1            2016-05-25   
    1            2016-06-25   
    1            2016-07-25   
    1            2016-08-25   
    1            2016-09-25   
    1            2016-10-25   
    1            2016-11-25   
    1            2016-12-25   
    2            2015-06-16   
    2            2015-07-16  
    2            2015-08-16  
    2            2015-09-16  
    2            2015-10-16  
    2            2015-11-16  
    2            2015-12-16  
    2            2016-01-16  
    2            2016-02-16  
    2            2016-03-16  
    2            2016-04-16  
    2            2016-05-16
```

I have found a query which will select the months between these dates but its adapting it to my table above, and multiple startDates and endDates I am struggling with

**spliting the months**

```
declare @start DATE = '2015-01-01'
declare @end DATE = '2015-12-31'

;with months (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MM,1,date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(MM,1,date)<=@end
)
select Datename(MM,date) from months
```

This query is limited to just one **startDate** and **endDate**, so I haven't expanded it to change the **DAY** of the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an in memory calendar table and then perform a simple query by joining to that:

```
-- Create a table with all the dates between the min and max dates in the 
-- data table
DECLARE @Calendar TABLE
(
    [CalendarDate] DATETIME
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT @StartDate = MIN(startdate), @EndDate = MAX(enddate) FROM YourDataTable

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Calendar (CalendarDate)
    SELECT @StartDate
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
END

-- Join to return only dates between the start and end date that match the Payment Day
SELECT D.PaymentId, C.CalendarDate FROM YourDataTable D
INNER JOIN @Calendar C ON C.CalendarDate BETWEEN D.StartDate AND D.EndDate
AND DATEPART(day, C.CalendarDate) = D.PaymentDay
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a date table and a simple inner join

```
DECLARE @tblPayments table (paymentID int identity(1,1), startDate date, endDate date, paymentDay int)

INSERT @tblPayments VALUES 
  ('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31', 25), 
  ('2015-06-01', '2016-06-30', 16)



;WITH dates AS -- Build date within the range of startDate and endDate
(
    SELECT MIN(startDate) AS Value, MAX(endDate) AS MaxDate FROM @tblPayments
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, Value), MaxDate 
    FROM dates WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Value) <= MaxDate
)
SELECT pay.paymentID, dates.Value AS expectedDate 
FROM 
    @tblPayments pay 
    INNER JOIN dates ON 
        dates.Value BETWEEN pay.startDate AND pay.endDate 
        AND DAY(dates.Value) = paymentDay
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: thankyou, this works also, alls i did was swap the INSERT code with a select statement and this fetched the whole table values